# How to put an sRGB image on top of a filmic render in the compositor while retaining their own sRGB-colors?

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management, filmic-blender

When I put an half-transparent sRGB image on top of a filmic render in the compositor, the transparent image will take the color-modus of the render (filmic in this case).

Is there a way to keep the sRGB-colors of the overlay image while using filmic for the  render image?